# append text from input without changing previous text in python

Tags: python, file

i want to make python create a file if it doesn't exist ,then take text from users input and append into my file and to be able to use my code several times without changing text before it

```
def register():
    f=open('1.txt','w')    
    f=open('1.txt','r')
    users=f.readlines()
    f=open('1.txt','a')
    while True:
        username = input('Enter your username: ')
        password = input('Enter your password: ')
        if username in users:
            print('this username is taken')
        else:
            f.write(f'{username}\n')
            f.write(f'{password}')
            break
```

this is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EAFP approach (which is more pythonic that LBYL):

- try to create a file
- handle specific exception if it exists
- either way do your logic in `finally` block

```py
try:
    with open("1.txt","x") as f: pass
except FileExistsError:
    print("File already exists!")
finally:
    with open("1.txt", "r+") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        username, password = input("Type username and password (separated by a space): ").split()
        if f"{username}\n" in lines:
            print('This username is taken!')
        else:
            f.writelines([f"{username}\n",f"{password}\n"])
```

Keep in mind though that:

- if the `username` and `password` are the same this won't work correctly (or at least not as expected imho, as homework figure out why :D )
- passwords in general should NOT be kept as plain text
- you should add the "boilerplate" `if __name__=="__main__":` thingy if it's a standalone and no part of a function/class etc
- you could wrap the `input` in `try...except ValueError` block to be extra safe when somebody enters a single value or three values and so on

Comments:
If you do something like this:

```py
    f=open('1.txt','w')    
    f=open('1.txt','r')
```

The 2nd line shadows the first one, so it makes no sense, it's the same as:

```py
x=2
x=3
print(x)
```

The 1st assignment is "dead"

- Most often you want to use `with` when handling files operations, otherwise it's your responsibility to close the file as well.

Comment: thanks! but i have a question. why did you use:  f"{username}\n" ; in if f"{username}\n" in lines: instead of using just "username"?

Comment: Because that's the string which is in the list actually. Add a print statement before and see for yourself 

Comment: but, username variable and f"{username}\n" gives the same , isn't it?

Comment: Nope type in REPL  `x=["a\n"]` and then `"a" in x`. You'll get False. "a" and "a\n" are different strings. Even if something is non printable, like `\t`, `\n` and a bunch of other stuff it is a part of the string if that's what has been saved.